# Separate suffixIcon for password visibility

Tags: flutter, dart

How to separate `suffixIcon` for password visibility? If I press icon on field password it also does the same thing on field confirm password.

[image: password visibility]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isObsecure = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Text Form Field'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: isObsecure,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isObsecure = !isObsecure;
                      });
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      isObsecure ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: isObsecure,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isObsecure = !isObsecure;
                      });
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      isObsecure ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to define 2 flags. 1 for password visibility and 1 for confirm:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isObsecure = false;
  bool isConfirmObsecure = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Text Form Field'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: isObsecure,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isObsecure = !isObsecure;
                      });
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      isObsecure ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: isConfirmObsecure,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isConfirmObsecure = !isConfirmObsecure;
                      });
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                      isConfirmObsecure
                          ? Icons.visibility_off
                          : Icons.visibility,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
///You can use the provider also to hide and visible the password icon. Hope this will work for you.

////This is my forgot password screen
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:form_field_validator/form_field_validator.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    import 'package:traveling/Provider/common/ObscureTextState.dart';
    
    import 'package:traveling/helpers/AppColors.dart';
    import 'package:traveling/helpers/AppStrings.dart';
    import 'package:traveling/screens/Employee/home/BottomNavBar.dart';
    
    class ForgotPasswordA extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _ForgotPasswordAState createState() => _ForgotPasswordAState();
    }
    
    class _ForgotPasswordAState extends State<ForgotPasswordA> {
      /// These variables are used for getting screen height and width
      double? _height;
      double? _width;
      ///controllers are used to get text which user enter in TextFiled
      TextEditingController confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
      GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey();
      String? confirmPassword, password;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
      }
    
      ///this widget is the main widget and it is used for building a UI in the app
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    
        return Material(
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: AppColors.white,
            body:Consumer<LoginProvider>(
                builder:(context, obs, child) {
                  ///Consumer is used to get value from the loginProvider class
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: _height,
                      width: _width,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(height: _height! / 22),
                            appText(),
                            SizedBox(height: _height! / 18),
                            Container(
                              width: _width! * .85,
                              child: Form(
                                ///define global key for validation
                                key: _formkey,
                                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    SizedBox(height: _height! / 50),
                                    TextFormField(
                                      controller: passwordController,
                                      validator: (value) {
                                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                          return "Please Enter Password!";
                                        } else if (value.length < 6) {
                                          return "Please Enter more than 6 digit .";
                                        } else {
                                          return null;
                                        }
                                      },
                                      obscureText:
                                      Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false)
                                          .isTrue,
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                      autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
                                      cursorColor: AppColors.black,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xff919AAA),
                                      ),
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: AppColors.textFieldColor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: AppColors.textFieldColor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: AppColors.red,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: AppColors.red,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: AppColors.textFieldColor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false)
                                                .toggleObs();
                                          },
                                          icon: Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context,
                                              listen: false)
                                              .switchObsIcon,
                                        ),
                                        labelText: 'Password',
                                        errorStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColors.red),
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0xff919AAA),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    //passwordTextFormField(),
                                    SizedBox(height: _height! / 30.0),
                                    ///password visibility handle by provider state management
    
                                    TextFormField(
                                      controller: confirmPasswordController,
                                      validator: (value) {
                                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                          return "Please Enter Password!";
                                        } else if (value.length < 6) {
                                          return "Please Enter more than 6 digit .";
                                        } else {
                                          return null;
                                        }
                                      },
                                      obscureText:
                                      Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false)
                                          .isConfirmPassword,
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                      autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
                                      cursorColor: AppColors.black,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color(0xff919AAA),
                                      ),
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: AppColors.textFieldColor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: AppColors.textFieldColor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: AppColors.red,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: AppColors.red,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: AppColors.textFieldColor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false)
                                                .toggleObsData();
                                          },
                                          icon: Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context,
                                              listen: false)
                                              .switchObsIcons,
                                        ),
                                        labelText: 'Confirm Password',
                                        errorStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColors.red),
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0xff919AAA),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: _height! / 28),
                            SizedBox(height: _height! / 22),
                            submitButton(),
                            SizedBox(height: _height! / 35),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );}
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      ///app-text Widget is used for app logo and icon in top side
    
      Widget appText() {
        return Container(
          width: _width! * 0.90,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(
                "assets/traveling-text-icon.png",
                height: 60,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
    
      ///for validation we used a submit button
    
      Widget submitButton() {
        return Card(
          elevation: 20.0,
          shadowColor: Colors.blue[100],
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            width: _width! * .85,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              // boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: AppColors.grey, blurRadius: 20.0)],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                  AppColors.blue,
                  Colors.blue.shade900,
                ])),
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if(passwordController.text==confirmPasswordController.text){
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EmployeeBottomNavBar()));}
                else{
                  print("password did not match");
                }
              },
              child: Text(
                AppStrings.submit,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }


////provider class
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:traveling/helpers/AppColors.dart';


class LoginProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isTrue = true;
  bool _isConfirmPassword = true;
  bool get isTrue => _isTrue;
  bool get isConfirmPassword => _isConfirmPassword;

  get switchObsIcons {
    return _isConfirmPassword ? Icon(Icons.visibility_off,color: AppColors.textFieldTextColor,) : Icon(Icons.visibility,color: AppColors.textFieldTextColor,);
  }

  get switchObsIcon {
    return _isTrue ? Icon(Icons.visibility_off,color: AppColors.textFieldTextColor,) : Icon(Icons.visibility,color: AppColors.textFieldTextColor,);
  }
  void toggleObsData() {
    _isConfirmPassword = !_isConfirmPassword;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  void toggleObs() {
    _isTrue = !_isTrue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```